# sizeof(long long) gives 8 but number overflows at 2**32

Tags: c, overflow, long-integer

```
long long n, prod, i;
n = 13;
prod = 1;

for (i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
    prod *= i;
}
printf("%d\n", prod);
printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long));
```

returns

```
$ 1932053504
$ 8
```

Result is clearly overflowing. But I don't get why this is happening with `long long`. `sizeof(int)` returns 4 [bytes] but the product is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is result overflowing?

Comment: Because using python: `math.factorial(13)-2**32 == 1932053504`

Comment: Read my answer please.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings (-Wall on gcc) and do something to fix them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the correct specifier. The `"%d"` specifier expects an `int` and you passed a `long long int`. According to the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard this will invoke undefined behavior. The observed behavior might be explicable but that doesn't mean it isn't rigorously *undefined behavior*.

Fix the code like this

```
printf("%lld\n", prod);
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long long));
```

and it should work as intended.

NOTE: enable compilation warnings and you should find out this kind of mistake very quickly.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks. But could you explain why you are using two different specifiers in your solution?

Comment: Because `sizeof` would give a `size_t` which requires the `"%zu"` specifier. It's not a `long long int`. You have to be very strict with the specifiers and the passed types because there is no other way to guarantee type safety.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

> Result is clearly overflowing.

That's a wrong conclusion. You are getting a truncated result.

When I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   long long n, prod, i;
   n = 13;
   prod = 1;

   for (i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
      prod *= i;
   }
   int truncated_value = prod;

   printf("%d\n", prod);
   printf("%d\n", truncated_value);
}
```

I get

```
1932053504
1932053504
```

The truncation happens due to the use of the `%d` format specifier.

You can fix that by using the correct format specifier.

```
   printf("%lld\n", prod);
```